# Inject HTML to the end of webpage on iPhone using javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and I want to inject some HTML to the end of it after its been loaded.

```
NSString* javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.innerHTML += '%@'", arbitraryHTML];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

The above code works, but only if arbitraryHTML is properly formated. E.g. the single quote ' is escaped as \' 
I'd like to clean up HTML in genearl so that I can pass it to a javascript function.

What are other characters that I need to escape or strings that could cause problems?

Here's an example of some HTML that breaks the above code:

```
<span><a onmouseover=\\\"jQuery\\'# >Test</a></span>"
```

Can this be done in genearl? What else am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think its a better idea if you separated the javascript from this code? That way, you don't need to do any escapes

Comment: I dont know javascript that well, how would you do that? Create some kind of var myVar = myHTMLString; then document.body.innerHTML += myVar; Still seems like you would need escape characters for the javascript...

Comment: @JibiAbraham I don't think this is possible with injection in a UIWebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the JS engine does not throw up. So you need to escape single quotes and backslashes. This should do the trick:

```
arbitraryHTML = [[arbitraryHTML
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"]
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"]];
```

Note that you also need to escape backslashes inside Objective-C strings as seen above.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that its not enough to escape just the single quote character. I also needed to escape /n and /r to make this work with all HTML in general.

There may be some other character that I missed, if I find a case I'll post it.